# Finding the Angular Material color palettes in node_modules for Angular 13?

Tags: javascript, npm, sass, angular-material, material-design

Prior to Angular 13 we could find the `theming.scss` file in `node_modules/@angular/material` and it contained the color palettes so we could use it to look up colors.

The `theming.scss` file also exists in Angular 13, but the color palettes are no longer there.  How do we find the color Palettes in Angular 13 Material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in: **"node_modules@angular\material\core\theming_palette.scss"**.

I can't believe nobody answered in 2 months!